# Add items to (sub) object of nested Json array

Tags: arrays, json, loops

I have a nested JSON-array and want to assign subitems to one of its sub- objects.

When I do for example:

```
jsonData[0].menu1[0].menu2[0].menuItem5 = "ok";
```

an item with the text 'ok' is added which is wanted behavior.

I want to create more of those menuItems (e.g. menuItem6,7,8,9,..) in a similar way. 
I tried writing a loop =>

```
var i = 6;
while (i < 20) {
jsonData[0].menu1[0].menu2[0].menuItem[i] = "ok";
i++;
}
```

but this doesn't work. How can this be solved please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of template literals and do as similar to this:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 'a',
  key2: 'b',
  key3: 'c'
}
let i = 1;
while (i < 4) {
  console.log(obj[`key${i}`]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Hello Geeky, seems interesting; thank you for your advise!! I tried to translate it for my code but I guess I am doing something wrong; this is the best shot I got:

       const obj = {
        key1: 'menuItem5',
        key2: 'menuItem6',
        key3: 'menuItem7'
       }
       let i = 1;
       while (i < 4) {
        console.log(obj[`key${i}`]);
        jsonData[0].menu1[0].menu2[0].(obj[`key${i}`]) = "ok";
        i++;
       }

which gives me the following error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'key1' of undefined'. Thank you!:)

Comment: can you send me the code sample you have i can help you

Comment: You would totally make my day with that one :) you can find it over here: https://jsfiddle.net/user979979/debzhnc9/4/ so what I am trying to do is adding subobjects to the menuItems object. I want to do that in a loop in order I can easily add a lot of new menuItems to that object and each of them has to have a unique name (so menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3,..) If I could do just: jsonData[0].menu1[0].menu2[0].menuItem[i] = "ok"; in a loop it would be solved but that doesn't seem to be allowed (which OK is pretty obvious but unfortunately I don't see another solution at this moment) Thank you

Comment: Wow amazing, I was already looking for a working solution for hours. I really appreciate this; thank you very much!! :)